# Looking for title of encryption machines book

Tags: stream-cipher, lfsr

I am looking for a title of book in the field of stream crypography.

I vaguely remember, that I saw this book at online shop (maybe amazon) near 5-10 years ago. This book is devoted to electronic machines cryptography (LFSR). Electronic encryption machine (perhaps, military) and LFSR in a "magnifying glass" (shows that LFSRs are used inside this machine) is drawn on the book cover.

Now I can't find this book on ebay, amazon, springer, etc. Please help to recall this book.

---

Note that this is *not* book recommendation request. My question covers an actual problem that I faced, and it has unique correct answer (book title). I think cryptography community is a best place where this question can be asked.

Comment: Have you tried a GoogleImages search of any keywords you can recall?

Comment: @Askar was it the right book? I think Aegean Park press may well have different books with similar covers.

Answer (score 2):

This is the book, I believe.

W Barker: *Cryptanalysis of shift register generated stream cipher systems*

I have (had? I need to check, maybe gave it away) a copy.

[image]